# all cordova plugins give undefined error

Tags: javascript, android, angularjs, cordova

I am working on a cordova android app. I am trying to implement push notifications. I tried so many ways using ngcordova, using normal plugin and some other methods all tries give me pushNotification undefined error. But the plugins are being installed without any error.

Then I followed [this](http://www.digitalaholic.com/push-notification-with-angularjs-and-cordova/) tutorial and did exactly the same, but it gives

```
device is not defined
```

error in the console. I used ripple emulator to test this. I installed it in the phone too, But the same error. I am using angularjs inside. and using cordova version 5.2.0. can anyone point me in a direction, I am really trying hard for the past 4 days but no luck. Please help me.

**update**

I have correct setup of angular and cordova I believe, because I already built an version of my app with the same setup and pc, and released it in play store. This problems arise only if I add some plugins like push, device, etc. In app browser and splash screen plugins are working fine though.

Comment: Have you included `cordova.js` file in your HTML ?

Comment: please look at http://ngcordova.com/docs/common-issues/

Comment: @Jugnu I found this just now by myself, I am trying..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure to include cordova.js, but it need to be load after angular.js.

If you want, here's a working seed:
  https://github.com/marioaleogolsat/cordova-angular-angularMaterial-seed

Just remember that some plugins can't be used in a emulation, so use cordova run  --device to make sure that anything is working properly.

Comment: Oh, also, if your calling an plugin inside of a controller and it isn't working, put it inside an deviceReady event... like this:


document.addEventListener("deviceready", function () {
        >> Plugin Call << 
}, false);

Also, once you're using Angular and Cordova, use ngCordova to help you with the plugins:
http://ngcordova.com/docs/plugins/

PS: Everything that I'm talking here is in the seed above.

Answer (score 0):

Hi It seems you have not done set up of Angular JS and Cordova properly.
Before doing push notifications. You must be ready with Angular JS and Cordova setup.

See below link:

[Angular JS and Cordova setup](http://www.digitalaholic.com/how-to-setup-cordova-angularjs-app/)

Follow above link and if it's done try to set up again push notifications.

Hope it helps you.

Comment: I already used the same setup and released a version of my app in play store, Now I am working on second version. So I think i have the right setup. But I am not really sure. If I remove the plugin code and build everything is fine. Problems arise only when i include any plugin.

Answer (score 0):

If Cordova is undefined you probably don't have it referenced in your index page. make sure you have this line.

```
<!-- Cordova reference, this is added to your app when it's built. -->
<script src="cordova.js"></script>
```

Comment: not cordova. If I add a plugin for example device plugin. calling the plugin inside code as device returns undefined.